# @font-face with multiple font-families

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

We're changing a font on our site from `FontA` to `FontB`. Seems simple enough. The problem is is that `FontA` is hardcoded everywhere, and even in places that we can't easily access (content that we're pulling in from external databases has this font hardcoded, etc.). What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontB', 'FontA';
    src: url('fontB.eot');
    src: url('fontB.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontB.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontB.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontB.svg#fontB') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;   
}
```

So both `FontA` and `FontB` use the same font. That way, all the legacy hardcoded content that uses `FontA` will start using `FontB` instead, and all future content will just use `FontB`. Is declaring multiple `font-family` legal and valid? Will it work cross-browser for browsers that use `@font-face`? If this won't work, I can just declare two `@font-face`, so it's not a huge deal. I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Is there a reason for not simply using the name FontA for the new font? The name you give in `@font-face` is just a name you choose, and by choosing a name that is now used in the CSS code just makes that name refer to your new font. Do you have some reason for retaining the old font somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to make do with two separate duplicate `@font-face` rules. The syntax for the `font-family` descriptor, unlike the `font-family` property, [does not permit more than one family](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-desc), so the syntax you have is invalid.

Attempting to specify it in two declarations just [causes the latter to override the former](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#at-font-face-rule) like you would expect in a style rule, meaning the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontA';
    font-family: 'FontB';
    ...
```

Is equivalent to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontB';
    ...
```